# Ссылка на исходную тему при улучшении правки

Tags: обсуждение, предложение

При нахождении в режиме улучшения правки захотелось взглянуть на текущее состояние темы, для которой улучшается правка, но не обнаружил ссылки. <s>Скриншот, к сожалению не сделал вовремя, а сейчас уже доступ к правкам недоступен (лимит проверки правок превышен).</s> 
Скриншот можно посмотреть ниже по тексту.

Собственно вопрос: я просто не заметил ссылку, и она есть, или её действительно нет? Если её нет, то, имхо, было бы неплохо её иметь для доступа к полной истории.

[Пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/82421) аналогичной страницы "низкого качества" (ссылка на исходную тему ещё есть):

[image: ссылка ещё есть]

После нажатии кнопки <kbd>Правка</kbd> ссылки на оригинальную тему уже не вижу:

[image: ссылки уже не видно]

А хотелось бы видеть.

Comment: Скорее всего есть, но чтобы сказать наверняка, потребуется описание поточнее, чем "в режиме улучшения правок" :)

Comment: @D-side, дополнил вопрос. Картинка заменяет тысячу слов :)